# Trying to develop an hybrid app using Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I am a native iOS developer and I am trying to make an hybrid app using cordova, but I am trying to change the index.html of cordova project, but when I build the app it doesn't show any change. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you editing the index.html file? In the /www folder or in the /platforms/../../ folder? You will have to run cordova prepare or cordova build to copy the index.html to the actual deployment to be packaged.

Comment: I am changing it in www folder, and its for iOS platform,I am building it but its still not showing any changes. Thanks